# Define a base rest controller in spring boot?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

Originally I just had `MyRestController`

```java
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
public class MyRestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/v1/endpoint", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> endpoint(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
        // etc - duplicate code across controllers with the one 
        // difference of a single function call and its corresponding params
    }
}
```

Then I realized that a lot of the functionality was reused across 6 other controllers so I consolidated them using an abstract `BaseController`

```
abstract class BaseController {

    public ResponseEntity<Object> run(String path, String[] params) {
        Object result = null;
        switch (path.toLowerCase()) {
            // case for each path
            case MY_PATH:
                result = someService.myPath(param[0]);
                break;
            case MY_OTHER_PATH:
                result = someService.myOtherPath(param[0], param[1]);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("No");
                throw new Exception();
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

and then I changed the class header for `MyRestController` to

```
public class MyRestController extends BaseController {
```

and this worked!

My questions are:

- How come I couldn't move the `CrossOrigin` from `MyRestController` to `BaseController` ?
- I was told to use an `abstract` class. Does this help at all in this use case?
- I replaced the duplicate try / catch with a single function using the `path` in a `switch` statement to use the correct method with the correct params. This seems hackish... Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for the annotation `CrossOrigin` https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/CrossOrigin.html

This is why it didn't work is because your `BaseController` doesn't have any methods to add to the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` so that is why it didn't work.

As far as the `BaseController` being abstract it is not necessary unless you have a method that you want your extending controllers to overwrite.

**Update about Switch**

That is really up to you depending on how many `controller` methods are going to fall into each case. If multiple methods fall into the `MY_PATH` case then I believe you are ok, but I can see where the cases could turn into a very lengthy switch statement. It's really up to you as the maintainer. In my opinion, I would break the switch statement cases into different methods and let the `controller` that extend call that method.  But that is personal preference.

Comment: Ok wonderful, I understand both of your answers. Thank you! Do you mind also taking a crack at the last question?

Comment: I suppose I'll keep everything the same and just change the `abstract` to a normal class. Thanks again!